# Express JS ignoring client.connect(), although cluster connection is ok

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I've just created a basic structure of express and mongoDB. Everything is ok except the code inside the client.connect not working.
I also tried with putting a wrong password in uri. But the app crashed.

- it means the mongodb also installed successfully.
- also I did a console.log(client) it was giving me info.

It seems everything is fine. Somehow the the client.connect() is not working.
Here's the code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})


const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
const uri = "mongodb+srv://mrasfo518:<password>@cluster0.fwjsg4v.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  console.log("database connected") //here's the problem  
client.close();
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

How can I solve this problem, and is there any problem can be with my computer firewall or something like this? Eg. Anti-Virus Application?

I'll really appriciate if you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to JS, so not sure about the reason, but I followed this link and it worked for me. It is possible that the convention you use here may have deprecated.

https://www.mongodb.com/languages/javascript/mongodb-and-npm-tutorial